# How to Identify excel link in Word Document using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-word, vsto

In one of our projects am storing the msword document in DB, modifying the word document programatically and generating pdf, which is working fine.

One of the usecase In the word document is, if user links an excel sheet with paste special link option.
This link works i.e data change in the excel reflects in the word document till the both the files in the end users local machine.

This does not work when the word document is saved to DB as blob and generating the pdf from that blob.

Reason identified is linked excel sheet in the word is not in the same path. So i was trying to figure out the link using aspose word api and trying to manipulate.

Any help on this is highly appreciated

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: please share some code - what you have done and where you fail.

Comment: No i haven't try an code.. i was using 3rd party software(Aspose)... if anyone has some clue can share

Comment: Have you tried posting this to Aspose?

Answer (score 0):

The [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office-48bcfe93-8a89-47f1-0bce-017433ad79e2) states the following:

> Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.

> If you are building a solution that runs in a server-side context, you should try to use components that have been made safe for unattended execution. Or, you should try to find alternatives that allow at least part of the code to run client-side. If you use an Office application from a server-side solution, the application will lack many of the necessary capabilities to run successfully. Additionally, you will be taking risks with the stability of your overall solution.

You may consider using the [Open XML SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/open-xml-sdk) or any third-party components designed for the server-side execution (like you chose).